# mac export path keep resetting

Tags: mongodb, macos

I try to install mongodb but I have to do this every time I open a new window or new tab

`export PATH=/Users/Jane/mongodb/bin:$PATH`

else I will get error of `-bash: mongo: command not found`. I try to open my bash profile by

`open ~/.bash_profile`

I can see `export PATH=/Users/Jane/mongodb/bin:$PATH`. What is wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell from the information given. What else does the .bash_profile do with `PATH`, and what does `echo "$PATH"` print (normally, i.e. when you haven't added to it manually)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin`

Comment: That's the default except for ":/usr/local/sbin" at the end. What's in .bash_profile?

Comment: I deleted the ~/.bash_profile, what should I do now? I've no clue why I do echo $PATH I got this `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
` Maybe I'm not the admin?

Comment: What else was in .bash_profile? If there was anything else in there, it could be really hard to recreate it properly. In general, when troubleshooting, you shouldn't delete things, as you can easily make things worse (or at least more complicated). It's much safer to rename them or move them someplace inactive. Basically, don't do anything irreversible unless you know exactly what the consequences are.

Comment: .bash_profile wasn't present until I created it, now I deleted it.

Comment: In that case, try this to recreate it: `echo 'export PATH=/Users/Jane/mongodb/bin:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile` and then open a new Terminal window and see if it has the updated PATH.

Comment: +1 for recreating it with the right path. I'm fairly sure there was a special character or space in the dotfile you deleted earlier.